# Issue with Lucee on Image write

Tags: coldfusion, lucee

I am getting a really strange error on Lucee for Image Optimization, I am storing the Images a BLOB in the Mysql database

So trying to do like this

I am getting an error in Lucee on this code;

```
<cfset myImage = imageReadBase64(uploadimage_attachment)>
<cfimage action="write" overwrite="yes" destination="#ExpandPath('optimizeImagesDir/#id#.jpg')#" source="#myImage#">
```

and this is the Error: `org.apache.commons.imaging.ImageReadException:Can't parse this format.`

Comment: Is this a CMYK image, or is it perhaps compressed via Photoshop with a custom color profile? This is not uncommon to see with custom image formats.

Comment: BLOB is binary. Base64 is a string.  Perhaps you're using the wrong function?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like, the data saved is not a valid image. Possibly you would need to use the insert query like below ( with `queryparam` of type `blob` ). Also you need to use `imageGetBlob()` to convert the data to BLOB.

```
<cfset obsolutePathOfImage = "D:/foo.jpg">
<cfset imageVariable = imageRead(obsolutePathOfImage)>
<cfquery datasource="test">
    INSERT INTO uploads( myimage )
    VALUES ( <cfqueryparam value="#imageGetBlob(imageVariable)#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_blob"> )
</cfquery>
```

And finally you need to use `imageNew()` function, in order to create an image variable from `BLOB` data.

```
<!--- "data" is the name of the query variable & "myimage" is the name of the DB column --->
<cfset filePath = D:/foo_from_DB.jpg>
<cfset myImageVar = imageNew(data.myimage)>
<cfimage action="write" overwrite="yes" destination="#filePath#" source="#myImageVar#">
```